# Swift WKWebView Configuration

Tags: uiwebview, swift2, swift3, wkwebview

I have a small application. I am opening youtube in webview and see the videos.
Everything is good but when I click the video it is opening new page and start video automaticly full screen.
I do not want auto start play video.

How can I do it?

My code:

```
let conf = WKWebViewConfiguration()
conf.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = false //Tried and Did not work
conf.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = true //Tried and Did not work

super.init(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it **conf.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true** .